# Displaying plus and minus of a length

Tags: debugging

I know that \the\somelength will show me the value of \somelength.  But how do I find out what the current stretch on that length is?

For instance, if I have

`\setlength{\footnotesep}{10 pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}`

and I later want to display what the plus and the minus are for debugging purposes, how do I do that?

First response was to use `\showthe`.  I tried that, but it doesn't give the plus and minus.  Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\scrollmode
\typeout{The footnotesep is \the\footnotesep,}
\showthe\footnotesep
\setlength{\footnotesep}{10 pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}
\typeout{The footnotesep is now \the\footnotesep,}
\showthe\footnotesep
\end{document}
```

Output on the console:

```
`The footnotesep is 6.65pt,
 > 6.65pt.
 l.6 \showthe\footnotesep

 The footnotesep is now 10.0pt,
 > 10.0pt.
 l.9 \showthe\footnotesep
```

`

But I want to see the plus and minus values.

Comment: `\showthe\footnotesep` (but `the\footnotesep` will give the same information in the document as opposed to the log)

Comment: Neither \showthe nor \the seems to be outputting the 'plus' or 'minus'.  [And now I don't seem to be able to use any markup, or even insert a newline--the moment I hit <Enter>, I get a posting.  Maybe I need to edit my original post?]

Comment: try \footskip :-)

Comment: @egreg:  Ok...that was not what I was expecting!  I think I need to ask a new question, because I'm sometimes getting extra vertical space between two footnotes.  I assumed that was because of rubber, but I guess that can't be the explanation.  (I also wonder why I'm not getting a warning when I try to do \setlength to \footnotesep, and include a plus and minus...)

Comment: Re my final post, the extra space between the footnotes turns out to be a minor bug in particular package.  My hypothesis that it was caused by \footnotesep was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't display the `plus` or `minus` components of `\footnotesep` because it can't have them, being defined by

```
\newdimen\footnotesep
```

which makes it a *rigid length* parameter.

If you do

```
\setlength{\footnotesep}{10pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}
```

LaTeX will set `\footnotesep` to 10pt (and this explains the result of `\showthe\footnotesep`) and typesets `plus 5pt minus 3pt`). If you do the setting in the preamble you'll receive a `No \begin{document}` error.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably thinking of the following construction (`\Footnotesep` in the example). Because the name is not reserved to the other construction (`\dimen`), the result is as expected.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\scrollmode
\typeout{The footnotesep is \the\footnotesep,}
\showthe\footnotesep

\the\footnotesep
%\setlength{\footnotesep}{10 pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}
\newlength\Footnotesep
\setlength{\Footnotesep}{10pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}
\typeout{The footnotesep is now \the\Footnotesep,}

B
\showthe\Footnotesep

\the\Footnotesep

\end{document}
```